# Using map() instead of for loop and writing shorter (better) code

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be a way to update this `for` loop to use `map()` instead, and is possible to shorten the `if` code too? I will write some examples:

```
def function(self, box):
    if len(box) == 0:
        for objID in list(self.dict.keys()):
            self.dict[objID] += 1
            if self.dict[objID] > self.maxF:
                self.deleteObject(objID)
        return self.object
```

This is just a part of the code but I would like to learn how to shorten it and get it to work faster perhaps, but the main point is I would like to learn to write it better.

Comment: You can change `for objID in list(self.dict.keys()):` to `for objID in self.dict.keys():` Otherwise this code is fine. One-liners don't necessarily run faster than full loops, and complicated one-liners are hard to understand.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi.  They need to call `list` because I suspect that self.deleteObject() is deleting the specified object from the dictionary.  You can't delete an object from a dictionary at the same time you're iterating over it.  Copying the keys is one solution.

Comment: And to original poster.  I agree with @PranavHosangadi.  Your code is nicely laid out and easy to understand.  There is nothing to gain here by using `map`.

Comment: You don't transform each object in a list of object (what `map` is made for) so don't try to use map here

Comment: Thank you all for the answer, yes @FrankYellin it is deleting object from dictionary so list have to be used.

Comment: The one change I would make to the code is to add a comment before the call to `list`.  Something like "# Copying the keys since the loop deletes elements from the dictionary."   You are doing something that looks strange to a reader.  Explain why you're doing it.

Comment: This isn't really a clean mapping operation, *don't use map*. You are mutating an object, map isn't for side effects. Just using map everywhere and writing "shorter code" is *not good code*. Code should be readable, maintainable, and not unnecessarily inefficient. The cleaner solution would be to create a *new dict*, whether it use a convenient syntactic shortcut or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say whether this will work without seeing your `deleteObject` function, but in general if I were going to modify a regular old dictionary like this I'd use a simple comprehension:

```
self.dict = {k: v+1 for k, v in self.dict.items() if v <= self.maxF}
```

(edit per comment) if there's meant to be an invariant where `self.object` and `self.dict` must have matching keys, then maybe I'd follow it up with:

```
self.object = {k: v for k, v in self.object.items() if k in self.dict}
```

However, if `self.dict` and `self.object` must have matching keys, it's a very strong clue that they should not be two different dictionaries in the first place -- instead there should be a single dictionary with compound values (objects, tuples, whatever).

Comment: `def deleteObject(objID):
    del self.object[objID]
    del self.dict[objID]`

Answer (score -1):

can be approched with MAP as:

```
map(lambda objID: self.dict[objID] < self.maxF ? self.dict[objID] +=1 : self.deleteObject(objID), self.dict.keys() )
```

Comment: This is not python, python uses `... if condition else ...`. And jsut write a regular function definition is you are going to assign it to a variable.